# How to increase Max upload size with Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a simple file upload form using Ajax request to handle it in backend. I setup my php.ini to accept larger files like 64mb. But when I submit the form the validation (ZF2) returns "File '' exceeds the defined ini size". This happen when i try to upload larger file. With small ones i have no problem. After some research i found that ajax requests have some limitations. These are my files. Any one can help.

```
<form id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <span id="upload-button" class="btn btn-success btn-file">
                Select image<input type="file" name="file">
            </span>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>



$('#upload-form').submit( function(e) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        data.append(key, value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload/process',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            ....
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            .....
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you restarted the apache service?

Comment: Yes i did it. I found the solution. I changed just upload_max_size parameter, and I had to change and post_max_size parameter which i forgot

Comment: Ah, great! You can post an answer to your own question for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in php.ini. Except the upload_max_size=64M, I had to change and post_max_size=64M